# Table iteration over two ranges

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

I am trying to create a `Table` where the iterator has two ranges with different iteration steps.

Let's consider a simple example: I want to find the square of the numbers from 1 to 9 in steps of 1 and from 50 to 90 in steps of 10. I could do it like this:

```
Table[i^2, {i, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90}}]
```

This needs a lot of typing though.

How can I iterate over two ranges without having to type all the numbers by hand?

Comment: `Table[i^2, {i, Join[Range[1, 9, 1], Range[50, 90, 10]]}]`

Comment: That's it! I read about `Join` and `Range` but somehow couldn't figure out how to combine them. Would you mind turning that into an answer?

Comment: @Ymareth answer is good as well, different but good :) Mine is just some basic stuff.

Comment: `Join[Range[1, 9]^2, (10 Range[5, 9])^2]`

Comment: @Kuba I assume that the `i^2` was just an example :D

Comment: @Öskå I know but allways good to know :P

Comment: @Öskå Why don't you make it an answer?  It's good to have *simple* answers too. Th existing answer is good, but far from ideal for a beginner ... there are way too many concepts to understand to make sense of Ymareth's answer.

Comment: @Öskå: I also think that having a simple answer is a good idea. Ymareth's answer seems to be very complete but I couldn't even say with my currently only very limited knowledge of Mathematica... And I actually used your solution in my problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since I've been asked to answer the question in a simple way, here it is:

```
fun:=#^2&
Table[fun@i, {i, Join[Range[1, 9, 1], Range[50, 90, 10]]}]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 2500, 3600, 4900, 6400, 8100}
> ```

Or like @Kuba said:

```
Join[fun@Range[1,9,1],fun@Range[50,90,10]]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 2500, 3600, 4900, 6400, 8100}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
chainTable[expr_, itr : {sym_, __?NumericQ | {__}} ..] := Apply[Join, Map[Function[Null, Table[expr, #], HoldAll], Unevaluated@{itr}]];
SetAttributes[chainTable, HoldAll]; (* As per Jacob's comment *)

chainTable[x^2, {x, 1, 9}]
```

{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81}

```
chainTable[x^2, {x, 1, 9}, {x, 10, 90, 10}]
```

{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 400, 900, 1600, 2500, 3600, 4900, 6400, 8100}

```
chainTable[x^2, {x, 1, 9}, {x, 10, 90, 10}, {x, 100, 900, 100}]
```

{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 400, 900, 1600, 2500, 3600, \
4900, 6400, 8100, 10000, 40000, 90000, 160000, 250000, 360000, \
490000, 640000, 810000}

```
chainTable[x^2, {x, 1, 9}, {x, {a, b, c}}]
```

{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, a^2, b^2, c^2}

Note that sym must be the same in all iterators.

An improved/simplified version which does not repeat the iterator symbol.

```
chainTable[expr_,{sym_,itr:{PatternSequence[_?NumericQ,_?NumericQ]|PatternSequence[_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ]|{__}}..}]:=Apply[Join,Apply[Table[expr,{sym,##}]&,{itr},{1}]];
SetAttributes[chainTable,HoldAll];

chainTable[x^2, {x, {1, 9}, {0, 6, 2}, {{a, b, c}}}]
```

{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 0, 4, 16, 36, a^2, b^2, c^2}

Check iterator sym is localized...

```
x = 1;

chainTable[x^2, {x, {1, 9}, {0, 6, 2}, {{a, b, c}}}]
```

{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 0, 4, 16, 36, a^2, b^2, c^2}

Comment: +1, but how about an attribute `HoldAll`? :)

Comment: hmm I guess then you would have to put `Unevaluated` around {itr}, and give the function in map attribute `HoldAll`.

Comment: HoldAll certainly, not following you with Unevaluated.  Can you provide an example that will break?

Comment: When you set `x = 1` it will break, regardless of a hold attribute

Comment: `SetAttributes[chainTable2, HoldAll];
chainTable2[
   expr_, itr : {sym_, __?NumericQ | {__}} ..
   ] :=
  
  Apply[Join, 
   Map[Function[Null, Table[expr, #], HoldAll], Unevaluated@{itr}]]` will work in that case :)

Comment: What he said ;) - I didn't know Function took a 3rd argument like that.

Comment: Ah it is nice `Function`ality :P. Remarks: I believe how I used it is actually undocumented, and the syntax highlighter does not like it. More standard would be to use it like `Function[y, f[y], HoldAll]`. Anyway now your code is halfway done :P, maybe either of us can edit?

Comment: All done, thank you!.

Comment: If you are only allowing for the iteration of a single variable I see no need to repeat it for each range.  I propose this syntax:  `chainTable[x^2, x, {1, 9}, {10, 90, 10}, {100, 900, 100}]`.  Or if you get fancy and allow multiple variables: `chainTable[x^y, {x, {1, 9}, {10, 90, 10}, {100, 900, 100}}, {y, {...}, ...}]`.  (+1)

Comment: True.  I was thinking of cutting and pasting from the two-Table example a bit too literally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Range.html) to do so:

```
Table[i^2, {i, Flatten[Append[Range[9], Range[50, 90, 10]]]}]
```